# How to add spaces for certain condition using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Let say, maximum length in textbox1 is 6 digits. so if the user enter less than 6, i want to add spaces in front of the text. I have no idea how to do that.

Example:
TextBox1 = "123"
output = "   123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.String` has a method called [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) - it adds whatever char you want to the left of the string to make it whatever length you choose:

```
Dim str As String
Dim pad As Char
str = "123"
pad = "."c ' Using dots instead of spaces so you can see it...
Console.WriteLine(str)
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(6, pad))
```

Result:

```
123
...123
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/GXCEM15392)

BTW, it also has `PadRight`...